# No wall switch for ceiling fan outlet

Tags: ceiling-fan

My bedroom fan needs replacing. There is no wall switch. It worked with remote. Have had nothing but problems with remote controlled fans and would like to install a pull chain only. I was told this is not possible with no wall switch to turn it off and on. Doesn’t make sense to me. So can I have a fan without a remote?

Comment: Is there no wall switch at all in your bedroom? If so, that's a problem...

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a wall switch to operate a fan. A fan can be installed to operate by the pull chain at the fan.

The bad news is that code requires a switch by the door to operate a light or an outlet that a lamp/light can be plugged into. This is so you don't have to enter a room in the dark. Are there any switch locations in the room? What about cover plates that might be covering up a switch location? How are the lights in your room controlled?